# Application.Transpose crashes when there is data in the cells

Tags: excel, vba, macos

This is a follow up question from "Application.Transpose stopped working when spreadsheet moved to anothe computer" that I posted yesterday. With additional info.

In the code below the program errors-out with a "**Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error**"  error on the following line.

`Warehouse_Col = Application.Transpose(wks.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Value)`

Note 1. That it crashes the second time I call `Application.Transpose` but works the first time. The only difference between the two calls, that I know of, is that know of is that `Range("B2:B" & LastRow)` has data and `Range("BZ2:BZ" & LastRow)`  has no data. (I am creating a 1D array for the results)

Note 2. If I call these two lines in the opposite order it crashes on the same range.

Note 3. Some have suggested not using Application.Transpose at all but I want to use 1D arrays as I have a lot of code I'd need to rewrite if I switched to 2D arrays.

Note 4. The value of LastRow is 26881 (the correct last row of data and not too big)

Note 5. This code worked fine until I moved it to a new computer  (MacBook Pro) the old computer was also a MacBook Pro.

Thanx for any help you can provide

```
TurnOffFunctionality          'Turn off at the start
     Dim StartTime As Double
          StartTime = Timer         'Get start time
     Dim RowCount As Integer
     Dim Warehouse As String
     Dim Warehouse_Col() As Variant
     Dim Results() As Variant
     
     ' wks is set globally aboveas one of two worksheets
     wks.Range("AA1") = "Ordinal"  ' add column header
           
           Results = Application.Transpose(wks.Range("BZ2:BZ" & LastRow).Value)
           Warehouse_Col = Application.Transpose(wks.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Value)

          For RowCount = LBound(Results) To UBound(Results)
               ' Do a bunch of stuff and put results in the Results array
          Next RowCount
          
          ' Write results back to sheet
          wks.Range("AA2:AA" & LastRow).Value = Application.Transpose(Results)
     
TurnOnFunctionality            'Turn back on at the end
'Call EndTimer("FindCustOrdinal", StartTime)
End Sub'''
```

Comment: Not sure about this (I don't use mac) try dropping the .value so you are transposing a range rather than an array.  Also try the worksheetfunction.transpose

Comment: Another problem with `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` is that it will give incorrect results (with no error message) if the number of elements is `>2^16`